# Como eliminar el ultimo registro ingresado de una tabla pivote de Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

tengo una tabla llamada `Documentos` y otra llamada `Estados` , lo que necesito es eliminar el ultimo registro del documento buscado en la tabla estado_documento.

> $documento = Documento::findOrFail($id);

si aplico lo siguiente

```
$documento->estados()->detach()
```

me elimina todos los registros de ese documento en especifico, yo quiero eliminar solo el ultimo registro insertado.

muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Tu tabla pivot tiene timestamps? Cómo identificas cual fue la última asociación?

Comment: Hola, si tiene timestamps

Answer (score 1):

de esta manera siempre va a buscar el ultimo id insertado

```
$documento->estados()->detach(\App\Estados::max('id'));
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, pero no he logrado eliminar el ultimo registro con el codigo que me indicas, la consulta no me arroja errores pero la tabla pivote se mantiene intacta y el ultimo registro no se elimina.

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de si quieres hacerlo con delete o detach puedes hacer una de estas dos opciones:

`$documento->estados()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->delete()`

`$documento->estados()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->detach()`

Comment: Tal vez podrías agregar la diferencia y links de documentación de *delete* y *detach*, de ésta manera tu respuesta quedaría más completa. ;)